# How to prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to\ (0,1)} \frac{x y - y}{x^2 + y^2 - 2y + 1}$ does not exist?

Tags: limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I tried $y=mx+1$, considering $(\frac{1}{n}, 1 + \frac{1}{n})$ and etc.

Comment: It looks to me that the limit is $-\infty$. The denominator is $\ge 0$ and the numerator goes to $-1$

Comment: Let $t=y-1. $ Then $ \lim\limits_{(x,\,y)\to (0,\,1)}\frac{x y - y}{x^2 + y^2 - 2y + 1} =  \lim\limits_{(x,\,t)\to (0,\,0)}\frac{(x-1)(1+t)}{x^2 + t^2} = ?$

Comment: Just look along the line $x=0$, $y=1+t$ as $t\to 0$

Comment: This looks like a calc 3 exercise. How rigorous of a proof are we talking about? With epsilons and deltas or just a clear argument why the limit blows up?

Comment: @zugzug just a clear argument, I checked it at WolframAlpha, so it's why I thought there is not limit (but maybe I did sth wrong) task: find limit or show that limit does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $x=0$, the term reduces to 
$$
\frac{-y}{(y-1)^2}.
$$
Hence, as $y\to 1$, above diverges to $-\infty$.